# induction, n + 2

Tags: induction

Task is to prove that at start of the N-round, count of hydras heads is divisible by 7. Rules of regrowing hydras heads are (all heads are cut off at start of each round, except black ones):

first head is brown (just 1 head),
by cutting brown head will grow 3 black, 3 pink and 2 green heads,
by cutting pink head will grow 3 black and 1 blue heads,
by cutting green head will grow 1 black and 2 white heads,
by cutting blue head will grow 3 blue heads,
and by cutting white head will grow 4 white heads.

So every odd round from $n \geq 3$ is divisible by 7

My questin is: can i prove this divisiblity by base $n=14 + 3^{n-2} + 4^{n-2}$ and inductive step $n+2$ not $n+1$? or would you use another procces to prove this task?

Comment: $P(n)$ is true in the case $n=3$ and $P(n) \implies P(n+2)$ then $P(2k+3)$ is true for all $k \in \mathbb N$